# Wordpress: Carousel plugin need to add button

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am new at Wordpress. I have added a plugin for Carousel Slider [from here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/carousel-slider/). I need to add buttons to every image of that slider with fixed position [image] . What I did is added button going into plugins `PHP file`. But this will remove my changes when I update the plugin.

Is there any other way so that I don't have to make any changes in the plugin?

Comment: Did you checked the FAQ at the bottom of the page? They have given several video tutorials!

Comment: move the Carousel  plugin from plugin folder to theme folder

Comment: @vel that isn't working

Comment: did you include the files in theme  functions.php?

Comment: which files? please elaborate

Comment: Yes! I moved all files from plugin folder to theme folder. Now what is code to  add in functions.php?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147596/discussion-between-shweta-and-vel).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got solution:

```
if ( is_page(4) ) {
        echo '<section class="carousel">';

        echo '<div class="owl-carousel-buttons">';
        echo '<div class="owl-carousel-buttons-inner-wrapper">';

        echo Pink_Button('#' , 'CONTACT US') ;
        echo Transparent_Button('#', 'Know More');

        echo'</div></div>
  <section/>';
}
```

I added this code in `my-theme/template-parts/content-page.php` and changed some CSS.